# Identify OPC-UA tags by ID even if renamed

Tags: opc-ua, opc

I am looking for information on the following question, but I can't find a clear answer (possibly not as I expect):

When renaming a tag in OPC-UA, is its BrowsePath kept or does it change?
The idea would be to use it as a unique ID of the tag, and even if the tag is renamed, not to lose the relation between old and new data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

BrowsePath follows BrowseNames, so if these names change, also the path changes.

NodeId is the unique identifier that should not change.

Comment: One comment now that I know where to look for (NodeId):
I see in the [documentation](https://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdkhp/1.5.1/html/_l2_ua_node_ids.html) that NodeId consists of NamespaceIndex, IdentifierType and Identifier. If this is correct, then changing for example the Identifier in the renaming, won't NodeId change as well?

Comment: If it is just renaming, the whole NodeId, including Identifier, must stay the same. Otherwise it is not renaming, it is a creation of a new node (and a deletion of the old one).